# Reverse iterating of map, which is accessed by getter / without copy

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

I have a class which reads / parses file and stores key-value pairs in map.

```
typedef std::map<std::string, const int> Data;
typedef std::map<std::string, const int>::reverse_iterator DataItReverse;
```

now I have a getter to get the data from "parser" class `inline Data getData() const {return _data;}`

All is great until I want to reverse iterate through map in question.

```
for(DataItReverse it_reverse = _parser->getData().rbegin();
    it_reverse != _parser->getData().rend();
    ++it_reverse)
{
    std::cout << it_reverse->first << std::endl;
}
```

Code above iterates in *normal* order (not reverse), when I copy data to temporary variable all works well:

```
Data tmpData = _parser->getData();
for(...)
```

I would like to avoid making a copy of data, since its going to be a large map.

---

please note that `_parser` is a pointer so data inside it are not copied multiple times

Comment: Are you *absolutely sure* that the only change you are making is the copy, and that the reversal of order is not due to something else. Are you also sure that the copy is really of the same data type as the original? Otherwise, this seems awfully strange, not to say unlikely.

Comment: How about returning a reference "Data& getData();"?

Comment: @AaronI yes I am sure, I am going to try out first answer posted by **paddy**, just give me a minute to work this out.

Comment: @cwschmidt I think same proposed user **paddy**, I am going to try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually getting undefined behaviour by iterating over a temporary that doesn't exist by the time you use the iterator.

Either make a copy (as you correctly identified to be a solution), or change your 'getter' to return a reference.

```
inline const Data & getData() const { return _data; }
```

This is actually standard practice.  You don't ordinarily return complex structures by value from a getter unless it's derived data (not stored in the class) or might change after the call (one example being multi-threaded environments where you need to acquire a lock to obtain the current state):

You will then have to use const-iterators.  I tend to use the `auto` keyword to save clutter in loops:

```
for( auto it = _parser->getData().rbegin(); it != _parser->getData().rend(); ++it )
```

To use non-const iterators you'd need to make a copy, or also provide a non-const 'getter'.  This isn't generally recommended, but maybe suits your purposes:

```
inline Data & getData() { return _data; }
```

Comment: Do I need iterator type at all while using **auto**s?

Comment: `auto` will deduce the type from the call (but is only available in C++0x onwards).  Since calling `rbegin` on a const object returns a `const_reverse_iterator`, then that's the deduced type.  Nothing is stopping you from using your current approach -- just typedef your iterator to a `const_reverse_iterator`.

Comment: Works perfect, when using non-const version, I will have to work out const version myself. Thank you! I did not think about (your first paragraph of the answer) _...undefined behaviour by iterating over a temporary that doesn't exist..._

Comment: But you do understand the implications of that paragraph and how it applies to the code in your question, right? =)  Glad to help.

Comment: Oh, definitely I do understand. Thank you.